# Error in Openstack Dashboard Authentication

Tags: openstack

After rebooting my openstack server, when I try to login in the **Openstack Dashboard**, the login fails and I get this error in the **horizon_error.log**:

```
[Sat Sep 14 21:44:31 2013] [error] DEBUG:openstack_auth.backend:Beginning user authentication for user "admin".
[Sat Sep 14 21:44:31 2013] [error] REQ: curl -i -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2.0/tokens -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "User-Agent: python-keystoneclient"
[Sat Sep 14 21:44:31 2013] [error] REQ BODY: {"auth": {"passwordCredentials": {"username": "admin", "password": "mysecretpassword"}}}
[Sat Sep 14 21:44:31 2013] [error]
[Sat Sep 14 21:44:31 2013] [error] Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1
[Sat Sep 14 21:44:31 2013] [error] DEBUG:openstack_auth.backend:Authorization Failed: <attribute 'message' of 'exceptions.BaseException' objects> (HTTP Unable to establish connection to http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2.0/tokens)
[Sat Sep 14 21:44:31 2013] [error] WARNING:openstack_auth.forms:Login failed for user "admin".
```

How can I fix this issue

Best Regards,
Pedro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your keystone service is down:

```
(HTTP Unable to establish connection to http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2.0/tokens)
```

Are you sure keystone is running?

Comment: You are right. But many times Keystone service does not get started while installing for Havana setup. I recently tried. So, I uninstalled Keystone, installed it again and did "service keystone stop" and "service keystone start" in order to complete a restart.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if your keystone service is running using :

```
ps -ef | grep keystone
```

If you are using devstack, then simply navigate to the devstack directory and rejoin the session

```
/home/<user>/devstack
./rejoin-stack.sh
```